# XQuery: Unexpected token "insert nodes" at start of expression

Tags: xml, xquery, oxygenxml

I'm using the Oxygen XML Editor to learn Xquery, and I've opened one of their sample files:

```
xquery version "3.1";
(:The Saxon EE processor must be set in the XQuery transformation scenario for this example. :)

declare base-uri 'file:/Applications/Oxygen%20XML%20Editor/samples/xquery/Update/';

(: How to insert a node in an XML document. :)
insert node

<product id="p7">
  <name>papa</name>
  <price>2100</price>
  <stock>4</stock>
  <country>China</country>
</product>

as last into doc("products.xml")/products
```

I would use this to transform the appropriate file, but the file doesn't pass validation. The validation error I get is

> F [Saxon-EE XQuery 10.6] Unexpected token "insert nodes" at start of expression

I tried to modify the code to match other examples and I still get the same error. I added the xquery version and base-uri to the sample to eliminate them as possible problems. Why is this happening, how do I fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oxygen, go to Preferences / XML / XSLT-XQuery / XQuery / Saxon HE/PE/EE, and tick the option "Enable XQuery Update". Also ensure that the transformation scenario for executing the query has "Saxon-EE" and "Enable XQuery Update" set.

You may need to restart Oxygen for the setting to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I am using BaseX v.9.7.3

I had to issue `set writeback true` command first.

Here is how to specify file system directory for the "products.xml" file:

```
declare base-uri 'e:\Temp\';
```

**XQuery**

```
xquery version "3.1";

(: set writeback true :)
declare base-uri 'e:\Temp\';

(: How to insert a node in an XML document. :)
insert node
  <product id="p7">
    <name>papa</name>
    <price>2100</price>
    <stock>4</stock>
    <country>China</country>
  </product>
as last into doc("products.xml")/products
```

Comment: Thank you, there doesn't seem to be a writeback option in Oxygen. The products.xml is in the same directory, plus I configured it in Oxygen to work on that specific file. Did you get the same error when you tried the file on BaseX at first?

Comment: No errors. Just it was not writing to the file on the file system. but just after `set writeback true' it started to write back to the file on the file system.

Comment: Please make sure that your first line is `xquery version "3.1";`

Comment: It does, I have updated. I have installed BaseX and it doesn't raise the error but I can't get it to output anything either

Comment: There is a command bar in BaseX. That's where you need to issue the set writeback true